# How to validate a custom component with vee-validate 3?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, vee-validate

I'm trying to get vee-validate to work on a custom component (which I called `"DatePickerInput"`).
Vee-validate works on other non-custom components.
The `v-model` on the `DatePickerInput` component works (the value is updated in the parent component).

The problem: no error messages are shown and the "errors" value stays empty:

```html
<validation-provider
    v-slot="{ errors }"
    :name="$t('StartDate')"
    rules="required">
  <div>{{ errors }}</div>
  <DatePickerInput
      v-model="startDate"
      :label="$t('StartDate')"
      :error-messages="errors" />
</validation-provider>
```

The `DatePickerInput` component is created like this (I removed some properties that seem unrelated):

```html
<template>
  <v-menu v-model="showMenu">
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
      <v-text-field
          v-model="date"
          :label="label"
          :error-messages="errorMessages"
          prepend-icon="mdi-calendar"
          v-bind="attrs"
          v-on="on"
          @click:prepend="showMenu = !showMenu"></v-text-field>
    </template>
    <v-date-picker
        :value="isoDate"
        @input="(isoDate) => this.date = isoDate"></v-date-picker>
  </v-menu>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['value', 'label', 'error-messages'],
  data() {
    return {
      date: this.value,
      showMenu: false,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    isoDate() {
      return new Date(this.date).toISOString().substr(0, 10)
    },
  },
  watch: {
    date: {
      handler(date) { this.handleInput(date) },
    },
  },
  methods: {
    handleInput(e) { this.$emit('input', e) },
  },
}
</script>
```

Why are errors not shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what my problem was.
Validation in vee-validate is triggered by events.
The important events are `"blur"`, `"change"` and `"input"`.

In the component that I made, events from the `v-text-field` were not propagated to the parent component. In other words: when `"blur"`, `"change"` or `"input"` were triggered on the `v-text-field`, no events were triggered on my custom `DatePickerInput` component.

To fix the problem, I created three methods:

```js
methods: {
    handleInput(e) {
      this.$emit('input', e)
    },
    handleBlur() {
      this.$emit('blur')
    },
    handleChange(newValue, oldValue) {
      this.$emit('change', newValue, oldValue)
    },
  },
```

And I added these methods to the `v-text-field` component inside the `DatePickerInput` component:

```html
      ...
      <v-text-field
          v-model="date"
          :label="label"
          :error-messages="errorMessages"
          prepend-icon="mdi-calendar"
          v-bind="attrs"
          v-on="on"
          @blur="on.blur && on.blur($event); handleBlur($event)"
          @change="on.change && on.change($event); handleChange($event);"
          @click:prepend="showMenu = !showMenu"></v-text-field>
      ...
```

To make sure that the events from `"on"` that the `v-menu` component uses were also triggered, I added `on.blur && on.blur($event);` and so on to the code. I'm not sure this is needed, but it works so I'm happy.